# Rename composer.dist.json to composer.json in PHPCI

Tags: continuous-integration

We are using https://www.phptesting.org as a continuous integration tester.

What is the right way to rename/update composer.dist.json to composer.json before running composer ?

Comment: Before I asked how you can rename parameters.dist.yml but that can be made simply using composer install

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the way to go if you own the server and it's not a security compromise is to activate the Shell plugin in PHPCI

https://www.phptesting.org/wiki/Shell-Plugin

Then you can use this at the very start and create directories, or give rights that you need before composer runs.

```
  setup:
      shell:
         - "update_params_rename_composer && do what you need && more"
      composer:
         action: "install"
```